# how to show category name and there product with image dynamic using asp.net with example

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

how to show category name and there product with images dynamic using asp.net with example

1.Sports

bat bowl wickets hand closed

1.books

c java dotnet cshar jquery

i need same about example.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category](
      [CategoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , [CategoryName] [varchar](100)
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_Category1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [CategoryID] ASC )
    );
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product]( 
      [PID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , [ImageName] [varchar](500)
    , [Pname] [varchar](500) 
    , [Price] [varchar](500) 
    , [CategoryID] [int] NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [PID] ASC )
    );
```

Comment: Do you have an existing database for this requirement?  If so, please share the schema.  I think you need tables for Product (containing image column), Category, and ProductCategoryAssociation.

Comment: i have two tables. Category and products... Category table: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category]( [CategoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [CategoryName] [varchar](100) , CONSTRAINT [PK_Category1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [CategoryID] ASC )

Comment: Product table:


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](


 [PID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,


 [ImageName] [varchar](500),


 [Pname] [varchar](500) ,


 [Price] [varchar](500)  ,


 [CategoryID] [int] NULL,


 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 


(


 [PID] ASC
)

Comment: i have two tables. Category and product. category for showing category name and product for showing list of products with images. 
images is storing in image folder. i think using joing we have to join two table but dynamic can explaint every think.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a product can have only one category.  In this case, a simple join of the 2 tables will do the job.  I see the image name but not the image itself in the database, so I assume you have a way to retrieve the product image based in the ImageName.

```
SELECT
      c.CategoryName
    , p.Pname
    , p.ImageName
FROM [dbo].[Product] AS p
JOIN [dbo].[Category] AS c ON
    c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
WHERE
    c.CategoryName IN(
     'Sports'
    ,'books'
    );
```